# Connect multiple azure resource groups via route-based vpn to same on-site firewall

Tags: vpn, firewall, azure, azure-networking, sophos

We are developing an app in Azure, made dev/test/prod ressource groups and want to connect these via Site-to-Site VPN to our On-Prem environment.
Connecting one of these ressource groups isn't a problem, connecting all of them is unfortunately.
We use Sophos XG Firewalls and I set up the connection as described here: https://community.sophos.com/sophos-xg-firewall/f/recommended-reads/126356/sophos-xg-firewall-v18-to-azure-vpn-gateway-ipsec-connection
My problem here is step 5/step 8. The vti/xfrm interface gets always the same ip from azure but naturally I can't use the same ip on multiple (virtual) interfaces on my firewall.
It's always:
int tunnel 11
ip address 169.254.0.1 255.255.255.252

So my question is and I already searched a lot and didn't find anything, am I able to change this IP somehow?
Does it even make sense to set up a s2s vpn from every ressource group or would best practice here a different scenario?

I googled up and down but it feels I'm the only one wanting to connect multiple ressource groups to the same on-prem gateway, but that surely can't be right.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://community.sophos.com/sophos-xg-firewall/f/recommended-reads/126506/sophos-xg-firewall-how-to-create-multiple-public-ip-on-the-xg-public-interface-in-azure

Answer (score 0):

You need to peer the virtual networks to each other to a central hub subscription where your network resources are deployed, and that way you can let the resources communicate with each other.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/hybrid-networking/hub-spoke?tabs=cli
[image]